# In React, When screen change, Component re-renders already rendered function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a flatlist and I use it with memo.

Screen 1.js Component

```
<FlatList
data={props.cars.results}
renderItem={(item)=> <SinleRowMemo item={item}/>}
/>
```

In SingleRow.js component;

```
export const SingleRow=(props.item)=>{
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>SomeFuncComesFromProps()}>
    <View>
          <Text>{props.car.brand}</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
export const SingleRowMemo=React.memo(SingleRow)
```

App.js

```
 <Route path={"/"} component={<Screen 1/>}/>
 <Route path={"/detail"} component={<Screen 2/>}/>
 <Route path={"/about"} component={<Screen 3/>}/>
```

The problem is that when I go to '/detail' screen and return to '/' page,
the SingleRowMemo function re-run again and renders all rows that have been already rendered.
How to fix this problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This cause react memo hook change your code as follows

```
const SingleRow=(props.item)=>{
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>SomeFuncComesFromProps()}>
    <View>
          <Text>{props.car.brand}</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
export default SingleRow
```

Comment: Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The memoization doesn't avoid the rerenders simply because the parameter is changing for each row. React.memo() is intended for cases where a component is rendered often with *the same* params and rendering is relatively expensive.

https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/